# Sending Email via a SMTP server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am developing a system, in which - I have a database of email addresses of a specific type of companies. There are near 10 lac addresses in this database. In this system I want to send a message to all these addresses by one click. I am using PHPMailer. I am using Yahoo SMTP for sending email. But when I send email to some numbers of addresses, it block my yahoo email account. I think, yahoo SMTP server dose not support this kind of sending email process. So, Is there any SMTP server that support this kind of sending email process?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "10 lac addresses" means "1,000,000 addresses", you are very likely to run issues with any free email service providers. Any reasonable email service will limit the number of emails relayed to prevent spamming and general abusing of the service.

You can either set up your own SMTP server (Postfix, Exim, etc. just to name a few free alternatives -- they may even run on your web server) or better yet, use a third-party commercial transactional email service which take care of email delivery. If your budget allows, I recommend the second option.

Answer (score 0):

to send the email to one million email addresses you need some commercial mail service as no email service provider will provide that much free mail. Its better you to buy some comercial mail service like chipmonkey, emailmarketing and few others